# Including Node modules in Spring Boot jar

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, gradle, npm, package.json

I have a Spring boot application that has a react front end. I have a package.json that contains all my node dependencies and use gradle for my spring boot dependencies.

When I want to build a jar for my production environment however, I am not sure how to include the node modules so that they ship with the jar (that way my react front end has all the dependencies it requires on prod). For my development environment I have a task that sets up the environment that looks as follows:

```
task setupEnv {
group = 'application-dev'

dependsOn 'npmSetup'
dependsOn 'npmInstall'
}
```

Alternatively would it be possible to use docker in some way to set up the modules on a production environment? I am very unsure about how to proceed with this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're serving the front end in prod from Spring do you actually *need* any Node deps? You need them to build the static HTML, JS and CSS to go into the jar, but not after that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I believe I will need them (but am not sure), my dependencies include stuff like material-ui which I am using for my UI.

Comment: All of that should end up in the bundled files, the output directory is designed to be statically served.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I think that makes sense, let me try it out. Thanks.

Comment: i have noticed that not all dependencies that need to be there. Only a some.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably use some kind of build step to generate front-end assets, e.g. Webpack/Gulp/NPM scripts. Point output of that JS build process to `src/main/resources`.

Your Gradle build should be based on [Spring Boot Gradle plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/). With that Gradle plugin, Gradle will automatically create fat JAR with all your front-end assets included. Spring Boot will serve it by default as front end assets of your web app.

You don't need to do anything special if you follow Spring Boot defaults.

Comment: I am sorry, but you did not answer to the question.

Comment: @NesanMano, actually I did answer it. But it could have been missed by devs that are not aware of Spring Boot ecosystem elementary basics. Now the answer is updated and more specific how these front end assets will end up in the JAR.

Comment: @luboskrnac upvoted for answering the question; however, I think it can use some tweak since `src/main/resources` is most likely checked into source control. What I usually do is to have webpack output to `build/resources`, and add that to `bootJar`task's classpath, that way `gradle clean` also removes webpack artifacts

Comment: I use .gitignore for this. Modern IDEs work with this git feature pretty well.